# Typo3 Fluid: use variable-value within var

Tags: templates, typo3, fluid

In my Fluid-Template, i want to get the title of a certain category. The variable {overwriteDemand.categories} gives back the id of the category. And now, to get the name of the category, i would need something like this

```
{categories.{overwriteDemand.categories}.item.title}
```

but like this, it's not working, so what i tried to do now, is making an alias to use it, and with the following code, catid gives back the correct value, but using it inside the other other statement, there's no result again.

```
<f:alias map="{catid: overwriteDemand.categories}">
    {catid}
    {categories.catid.item.title}
</f:alias>
```

I also tried

```
 <v:var.set name="category" 
            value="{v:var.get(name: 'categories.{overwriteDemand.categories}.item.title')}" />
 {category.name}
```

but it brings up a ViewHelper-Error, even if it's described in the Manual:

https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/1.8.0/Var/SetViewHelper.html

Any ideas how to solve this or what's the error in the second part?

Comment: The last version should work. The only problem that I can imagine is that the `v:var.*` viewhelpers were renamed to `v:variable.*` in recent versions of EXT:vhs. So can you try with `<v:variable.set name="category" 
            value="{v:variable.get(name: 'categories.{overwriteDemand.categories}.item.title')}" />` please?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Ok there's no error anymore, but it's seems to be empty an nothing appears...

Comment: What does `<f:debug>` print out for `{category}`, `{overwriteDemand.categories}`, `{categories}` and maybe `{_all`}? Can you see a name mismatch or something there?

Comment: {overwriteDemand.categories} gives back the right category id, {category} gives me the category-name, but +1, so its not the name of cat=3 if {overwriteDemand.categories} = 3, but the name of cat=4. and the next problem i have is, that {_all} cuts of at some point (not because of maxDepth) and it doesn't show the rest of the entries at all... Do you know how do change f:debug to show everything?

Comment: The problem with the wrong category comes probably from the misconception that the array `categories` uses the `id` of the categories as indices. It doesn't, it just numbers the categories from 0 to (number of categories - 1). So your approach won't work, especially after you've hidden or deleted some categories. Better use a loop to walk through the array of categories and check each one if it has the right uid, and if so, assign that category to the variable `category`.

Comment: In case you wonder why the `<f:debug>` code is truncated, objects are only rendered once. Therefore search for the objects in the debug tree above your current possition of the debug output.

Comment: Hey pgampe, thanks for your comment, but the truncate happens when i do a debug {_all}... so the highest level of objects are included, or am i wrong?